How do courts decide which right prevails when fundamental rights conflict?

In the U.S. Supreme Court case Masterpiece Cakeshop v. Colorado Civil Rights Commission, the baker argued that his rights to free speech and religious freedom justified his refusal to create a wedding cake for a same-sex couple. Conversely, the couple argued that their right to equal access to services was being violated. In the Masterpiece Cakeshop case, the U.S. Supreme Court ultimately ruled in favor of the baker, not on the basis of prioritizing one right over another, but because the Colorado Civil Rights Commission showed hostility towards the baker’s religious beliefs during the proceedings. The Court, however, did not establish a clear precedent on how to resolve the clash between free exercise of religion and anti-discrimination laws, leaving the broader question open.

Is there a method that courts use to balance such rights?

Another example is in Burwell v. Hobby Lobby, where the U.S. Supreme Court prioritized religious freedom over women’s access to contraceptive healthcare under the Affordable Care Act. The decision was based on the Religious Freedom Restoration Act, which requires the government to use the least restrictive means to achieve its goals.

In contrast, the European Union often uses the principle of proportionality, where conflicting rights are balanced to minimize infringement on each right. What factors or reasons do courts consider when deciding which right comes out on top?
Scope:
The question is intended as a broader question on how courts decide things, but if it helps when answering a US context.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

In U.S. law, there is no widely accepted legal principle that governs how to reconcile constitutional rights under the U.S. Constitution that seem to conflict with each other.
No right is absolute and generally, judges try to reconcile the inconsistency by finding mutually acceptable exceptions to a right. But when all else fails they just do whatever makes the most sense in light of reason, experience, and past precedents interpreting somewhat similar situations.

I don't entirely agree with Ohwilleke's statement.
First of all, consistent with Oh's response, U.S. courts employ a doctrine of constitutional avoidance, in that they will try to find any rational interpretation and construction of each party's rights that serves to avoid creating any clash that needs a constitutional opinion to resolve it.
To the extent that the constitutional clash is completely unavoidable, however, the general interpretative canon for wholly irreconcilable legal provisions is the last-in-time rule (which is where I would differ from Oh's answer), provided that the last-in-time constitutional enactment was publicly understood when enacted to touch upon the substance of the competing, earlier-in-time constitutional right.

Can you elaborate on what the last-in-time rule is? If it refers to the time that each law or amendment was enacted, how does it apply when the conflict is between rights in the 1st Amendment (freedom of speech vs. freedom of religion)?

I agree that there is a last-in-time rule, in theory, but in practice, it is so unreliably applied in this context that it isn't predictive of outcomes and ends up being one part of a multi-factor test with no one factor being decisive. For example, in the OP's Masterpiece Cakeshop case, 14th Amendment equal protection rights are more recent than 1st Amendment free speech rights. Also, as Barmar notes, this doesn't resolve conflicts within different provisions of the Bill of Rights which were all added at once.

@ohwilleke: My understanding of why this is is the specific wording of the 14th amendment causes the original 10 to be applied to the states when previously they were not; which means the last in time rule doesn't do anything here.

@Joshua The incorporation doctrine, which relies upon the due process clause of the 14th Amendment, is the current legal theory upon which the Bill of Rights is applied to the states. And, the equal protection clause of the 14th Amendment and the due process clause of the 14th Amendment were, of course, adopted at the same time. But while that is the subtle and somewhat clever argument, usually the Bill of Rights would be considered first adopted, even though it was incorporated against the states later.

@Barmar In Scalia and Garner's Reading Law, it's canon 58, which they call the Presumption Against Implied Repeal, which starts at 327, which itself cites The Federalist No. 78: "The rule which has obtained in the courts for determining their [i.e., conflicting statutes] relative validity is that the last in order of time shall be preferred to the first."

@ohwilleke In Masterpiece Cakeshop the rights of the complaining couple weren't relevant: they weren't a party to the suit; it was an enforcement action by the state against the shop owner. While the state can pursue actions that protect a complainant's rights under the standing it has out of parens patriae, it must at least also have a quasi-sovereign interest of its own that it seeks to defend; the state cannot intervein merely for the sake of protecting the complainant's constitutional rights where the complainant is capable of defending those rights themselves.

Could you include links/explanations to the "last-in-time rule" and "doctrine of constitutional avoidance"?

@SchwarzKugelblitz Last-in-time rule, a.k.a. "Leges posteriores priores contrarias abrogant." Where law B postdates law A, and one cannot follow B w/o violating A, then A must give way. Courts presume the legislature did not intend any conflict, and will adopt less-than-optimal but reasonable interpretations to avoid them; but where the conflict is unavoidable, law B wins.

@SchwarzKugelblitz Avoidance canon: where two reasonable interpretations exist, interpretation A is preferred to B where B raises doubts about constitutionality or tends towards causing other constitutional problems.
This very concise summary of the canons in Scalia and Garner from Uni. of Houston Law (https://tinyurl.com/e8uczdvy) describes both: "presumption against implied repeal (last in time)" and the "avoidance canon."

@SchwarzKugelblitz: I will add to this. There were a couple of cases in the past two years involving the voting rights act and the refusal to create sufficient numbers of minority districts. These cases had rulings that ended up weakening the 1965 voting rights act. I was able to demonstrate mathematically that upholding the intent of the voting rights act without resulting in completely disenfranchising the majority of the population would overturn the 1929 Permanent Apportionment Act. One of the cases would have required literally adding house members to fix.
